# What is the difference between GetClientRect and GetWindowRect in WinApi?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

What of these should I use in InvalidateRect to refresh my window? And why?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The window rect includes the non-client area, i.e. the window borders, caption bar etc. The client rect does not.

`GetWindowRect` returns a rect in screen coordinates whereas `GetClientRect` returns a rect in client coordinates.

`InvalidateRect` receives a rect in client coordinates. If you want to invalidate your entire client area, then pass `NULL` to `InvalidateRect`. You could pass in the rect returned by `GetClientRect`, but it is far simpler and clearer to pass `NULL`.

Answer (score 17):

A very simple explanation is that `GetWindowRect()` gives you the rectangle that includes the borders of the window. `GetClientRect()` gives you the rectangle that excludes the borders - the area that is allocated to the window specific drawing.

Please note that `GetWindowRect()` returns a rectangle in screen coordinates - coordinates that are relative to the screen/monitor. `GetClientRect()` returns a rectangle that is relative to itself.

Answer (score 12):

`GetClientRect` gets the coordinates of the window's client area. Specifically this is the area **inside** the window chrome and **excludes** the header etc.  One of the comments on [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503(v=vs.85).aspx) sums it up quite well:

> I would say that this function return size of the area that I can render to.

`GetWindowsRect` gets the coordinates of the whole window. This **includes** the header, status bar etc. However according to a comment on [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=VS.85).aspx)

> Apps under Vista that are not linked with WINVER=6 will receive a misleading set of values here, that do not account for the extra padding of "glass" pixels Vista Aero applies to the window.

So unless this have been fixed for Windows 7 double check the result you get and make sure you have the correct value of `WINVER`.

Answer (score 8):

From MSDN:
**GetWindowRect**
Retrieves the dimensions of the bounding rectangle of the specified window. The dimensions are given in screen coordinates that are relative to the upper-left corner of the screen.

**GetClientRect**
Retrieves the coordinates of a window's client area. The client coordinates specify the upper-left and lower-right corners of the client area. Because client coordinates are relative to the upper-left corner of a window's client area, the coordinates of the upper-left corner are (0,0).

**More**: client rect does not include title bar, borders, scroll bars, status bar...

Comment: Thanks for the point about relative coordinates being returned from GetClientRect().

Comment: Important note about scroll bars