# c++ win32 Relative position to desktop

Tags: c++

How will i get a application x y position relative to the client screen?

I tried but all unsucessful so can anyone help.

```
RECT pta;
GetWindowRect(hWnd,&pta);
POINT Rpt = { pta.left, pta.top }; 
ScreenToClient(hWnd, &Rpt);
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: What is a client screen?

Comment: @immibis I mean dedktop

Comment: Then just don't call ScreenToClient? Window coordinates are normally relative to the desktop.

Comment: @immibis I want to set my cursor position to middle in the window of my app.

Comment: I'm not sure what that's got to do with ScreenToClient.

Comment: Maybe you should try [GetClientRect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561049/what-is-the-difference-between-getclientrect-and-getwindowrect-in-winapi) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to set my cursor position to middle in the window of my app

If I understand right, you want to call the SetCursorPos() windows API call to center the mouse cursor to your window. That function takes screen coordinates.

GetWindowRect() returns the window top and left coordinates already in the screen coordinates, so no transform is necessary.

To get to your window's center coordinates, you just need to add half of your window's width and height to the top-left point's coordinates. Then you can call SetCursorPos().