# GetWindowRect is not giving left and top values correctly

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to change my window background but the function GetWindowRect is not getting the left and top values right. The FillRect function only fills a quarter of the screen and the rest is left transparent. When I set the left and top values manually it works fine, filling the whole window.

```
case WM_ERASEBKGND:{
                hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
                RECT rect;
                GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
                rect.left = 0; //It only works
                rect.top = 0;  //if I do this
                FillRect(hdc, &rect, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(240,240,240));
                EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
                }
                break;
```

Comment: `GetWindowRect` -> `GetClientRect`

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561049/what-is-the-difference-between-getclientrect-and-getwindowrect-in-winapi) explains the difference between the window and client rects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Richard Critten suggested, use `GetClientRect()`. `GetWindowRect()` returns the screen coordinates of the window, whereas `GetClientRect()` returns the coordinates of the client area within the window where the application's graphics are rendered.